# multiple uses for original software

Tags: design-patterns, programming-practices, performance, development-process

How does a programmer figure out multiple uses or applications for the original software he/she has written. I am an artist who has designed a RPG game with several different and separate applications that are all linked and combined in the software that I am attempting to find alternate uses/applications for. Since I normally don't think like a programmer I am asking is it possible to take the same concept or the properties of the program and find other uses for the software?

Answer (score 2):

> How does a programmer figure out multiple uses or applications for the original software he/she has written.

I've seen this done often and despite what other answers say systematically. It's done by breaking down and grouping your application's operations by the functionality they perform. You will find that you have lots of different categories that overlap. You then think about what different types of customers might need in the general category of your app. You then decide which of those customers you wish to pursue and put in the functions that they need.

Here's a contrived example. Let's say you've written an application to do some photo manipulation. You break down your applications various operations - color corrections, distortions, stylizations, blurs, sharpening, etc.

Next, think about the types of customers who might want to manipulate photos. You have high-end art and magazine photographers who need a lot of options, a lot of control and good performance. You have mid-range users who need to do a more limited set of moderately complex operations for things like wedding photography, corporate event photography, etc. Finally, you have low-end users who are taking pictures with their phones and want to do some fixing up, but with minimal amounts of controls, and probably want some whimsical stylizations to add to their pics.

Finally, you look at the market for each of those. The high-end users are few and far between, but you can charge an arm and a leg if your software is good enough. There are more mid-range users, and they'll pay since it's for work, but only so much. The low-end users are abundant but they either want free or very low cost.

Armed with this information, you think about what combination of existing software, users, and market size you can achieve and choose features for your new app or apps based on that.

If you are careful about how you build things, you can make them expandable, and you can make different apps complimentary. For example, users might start out wanting to just add silly distortions to their personal photos. You might later create a service where they can upload and share them. You can also make a middle-range app that does more serious stuff. You can re-use the photo-sharing service, but re-brand it and make nicer templates for the mid-range users. Etc.

You might also find that what started off as one type of app has pieces that can be re-used by other types of apps. For example, those photo filters might work on video. Or perhaps game developers need them for creating their artwork. Heck, maybe there's even a serious scientific use for some of them!

Answer (score 0):

> How does a programmer figure out multiple uses or applications for the original software he/she has written.

You have to ask your users, how else?

Encourage feedback from them, either by asking them on your web site (providing a public or private commenting section), by telling them an URL of a feedback form somewhere in an info box of the software, or by making systematic surveys. Nowadays, lots of software vendors provide public discussion forums for asking dedicated questions or providing issue reports. Just observe what your users report there.